# Is java byte code position independent?

Tags: bytecode

I want to inject bytecode in a java project. I am wondering if it is possible to insert instructions before a byte code method.
In other word, do you now if java byte code is PIC ?

Answer (score 0):

Java bytecode is interperted by a virtual machine, so there is no notion of PC or PIC like there is with native code.

As for inserting instructions at the beginning of a method, that is likely to break things. Specifically, exception handlers refer to offsets within the bytecode, so you'll have to update all of those. You'll also have to update the stack map table, and any other metadata (like line numbers) that might be present.

Comment: …and the `switch` instruction padding…

Comment: so you mean switch structure is position dependent ? Tools like javassist gives us a method called insertbefore. Does this method apply fix to existing code ?

Comment: @Bob5421: the instructions [`lookupswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lookupswitch) and [`tableswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.tableswitch) use pad bytes to align their embedded table to a position divisible by four. I suppose, tools like Javassist will take care.